# Living in Satya Yuga, Treta Yuga and Dwapara Yuga

Tags: yuga

It is said in all Vedas and Puranas that everything happened in and around India during Treta Yuga and Dwapara Yuga.

Then what about the rest of the world during that time?

Was it barren? Was nobody living there?

I have heard about the Aztec World and the Pyramids of Egypt. Were they present the same time as Treta and Dwapara Yuga?

Also, in Satya Yuga, who lived? Were there human beings or just Manu and the 7 sages? And did they live on Earth or somewhere else or spread across the entire universe?

Comment: I think yes everyone was in the same Yuga across the Earth. Because as I understand it Yugas are not restricted only to India but the whole world. Also I think there were not only humans in Sathya Yuga, it was an Earth filled with diverse creatures similar to how it is now. I think it is mentioned in the story of Manu. Good q sir

Comment: @Sai Actually there are confusing statements in a lot of scriptures that suggest that the four Yugas are limited to Bharata Varsha.  Like the Vishnu Purana [says](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp059.htm) "In the eight realms of Kimpurusha and the rest (or all exclusive of Bhárata) there is no sorrow, nor weariness, nor anxiety, nor hunger, nor apprehension; their inhabitants are exempt from all infirmity and pain, and live in uninterrupted enjoyment for ten or twelve thousand years.... **In those places there is no distinction of Krita, Treta, or any succession of ages**."

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan that is quite confusing :) but then different scriptures and different saints do appear to say different things about the Yuga system in general. I also remember reading one of your comments that the Yuga system is hardly if at all mentioned in the Vedas or Upanishads.Thanks for sharing that information Keshav.

Comment: @Sai Well, I haven't found any scriptures that explicitly make the opposite claim, for instance a claim that the people of Illavrita Varsha experience four Yugas, which is what makes this so confusing.  But yeah, it is true that the Yugas are almost never mentioned in the Vedas.  But that's a species of a more general phenomenon; people in the Vedic period didn't even know that Matsya, Kurma, and Varaha were incarnations of Vishnu!  There are a great many facts that people only learned once the Puranas were composed by Vyasa, see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6896/36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan ok is there any documentation of what those other lands are that are spoken of. For example, like Illavrita Varsha is present day England or something like that? That would then be easy to verify if the people are really so well off there that they have exemption from pain and live for uninterrupted enjoyment for ten or twelve thousand years :P !!

Comment: @Sai Well, the ten to twelve thousand years part doesn't bother me so much; that can be easily explained by saying that whatever deformities humans got when the Kali Yuga began in India spread to the rest of the world.  What confuses me more is the notion that the Yuga Dharma may be different in different parts of the world.  (Like some place is said to be in perpetual Treta Yuga, for instance.) In any case, at least some of the places mentioned in Hindu scripture are easily identifiable.  Kimpurusha Varsha is the land on the other side of the Himalayas, for instance.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan well I can understand physical deformities being spread but i don't get how they would live in 'uninterrupted enjoyment' would be undone as easily as you put it. also other parts of the sentence like anxiety cannot really be a physical trait to be spread. But yeah what you said would make it all the more confused :) I am pretty sure people all over the world are just as anxious or do not have uninterrupted enjoyment so

Comment: @Sai I found a similar statement in the Kurma Purana that the Yugas are limited to Bharata Varsha: http://www.indianscriptures.com/Content/Articles/PDFs/30619/79_chapter_47.pdf "The people of learnings have spelt out that there are the four Yugas in the Bharata subcontinent, viz. Krita, Treta, Dvapara, and Kaliyuga.  These Yugas are found no where else."

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan That statement makes things more confusing I guess. Perhaps one would have to look at the exact sanskrit version to get deeper out.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I think it is due to Kalpa Bheda. I'm saying this because same scriptures giving the location of Mt. Meru at the center of JambuDwipa. Moreover they talk about 9 dvipas within Bharat Varsha surrounded by different types of rivers carrying milk, sugarcane juice etc. Gautam Buddha's remarks on Mt. Meru can be accepted as more authentic as these are latest, & quite consistent..

Comment: The Greeks, some Europeans, and other non-Indian civilizations also had the concept of 4 ages with decreasing morality.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan You're right. Four Yugas are for only Bharatvarsha.

Answer (score 1):

One must understand that the created world cannot be in a singular state. There are multiple cycles within cycles. The larger cycles are with respect to the divine and determines how much of percentage of the divine can one be born with which will also determine how much one can understand the divine. The smaller cycles will determine the type of environment or mind space one gets to experience. For example, if you are in a war zone it is Kali yuga, if you are sitting in a temple you are in Treta Yuga. If you are quietly meditating you are definitely  in Satya Yuga. If you blame others for your follies you are in Kali Yuga. If you take responsibility and understand that the solution to your problems lies within you are in satya yuga.

In the below link Bhishma Pitamahan is explaing to Yudishtir about the Yuga.
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22028/12223

The below link gives what Sri Krishna explains yuga during Mahabharata war.
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21454/12223

Comment: "For example, if you are in a war zone it is Kali yuga, if you are sitting in a temple you are in Treta Yuga. If you are quietly meditating you are definitely in Satya Yuga" --is this your own opinion, or you got from some source?