# Yuga changes and age difference

Tags: mahabharata, yuga, kali-yuga

I have kind of a stupid question, but I believe it's valid.

What exactly happens when a Yuga changes from Satya Yuga -> Treta Yuga -> Dwapar Yuga -> Kali Yuga?

I don't have any reference to cite, but it says that in Kali Yuga, the average age of a person is 100 years whereas in Dwapara Yuga it's 1000 years and Treta Yuga 10000 years (I guess).

Then what will happen during transition of one Yuga to another; let's take the case of Parikshit and Yudhisthir. I believe that Kali Yuga had started at the time of Parikshit. So, how exactly does the age difference happen? Behavioral changes can be applied directly but structural changes to human body is hard to go unnoticed.

Is it immediate or slow? How do people react to the change?

I know it might sound crazy, do we have any reference to that in Hindu scriptures or the history books?

Comment: The process of structural changes must be gradual and not immediate as we even see today that height of the people in cities are slowly becoming smaller as compared to that in our grand parents or great grand parent's time. To prove about the height difference I can recall an incident where Revati was especially made smaller in height to marry him to Balarama. Revati and his father belonged to different yuga.

Comment: @Aby, though I don't deny what you say, but just for records: The average heights in China has surpassed their forefathers (and even Indians) in last few decades. The early human fossils are much shorter than current Europeans. Yes, in so called Kaliyuga the average ages of humans can be lesser due to *adharma* by few years or decades, but by centuries is just an overhyped perception.

Comment: @Aby, as mentioned here the world will not be destroyed at the end of KaliYuga.: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2875/what-exactly-happens-at-end-of-kali-yuga-how-will-the-world-be-destroyed/8850#8850 
so how things will be there when Satyuga starts.

Comment: @NixitPatel i never said world will be destroyed. But its a cycle of changes. structural changes are related to what kind of environment, food habbits, pollution level, greenary, etc is there. So if things changes people can come back to getting structually better. An example could be fuel reserves will end after a certain time and then pollution level can drastically decrease as people will start using other alternatives so may be then we will see some changes.

Comment: Yuga's are counted in Divine Years. Anything Divine is within you. The basis of time starts with a breathe and ends when there is no breathe as far as a human life is concerned. If the divine within you is strong you live longer otherwise it is not so. The concept of Yuga is clearly explained by Bhishma Pitamahan in his discussion with Yudhistra and also by Sri Krishna before the war. Generally I see people in this forum commenting on all kind of concepts without any grounding in Jyotish. Jyotish is the eye of the Vedas. 99% of Vedas is Jyotish. The Itihaas and Puranas are a way of putting a c

Answer (score 1):

According to Coomaraswamy, "Each Manvantara is followed by a Deluge, which destroys the existings continents and swallows up all living beings, except the few who are preserved for the repeopling of the earth."

A single Manvantar is approximately 71 maha-yugs.

This implies that at the end of every 71 four-Yug cycle there will be a Great flood. I think this Great Flood may refer to the end of Ice Age, Deglaciation period. Note that the ancient city of Dwarka was submerged at the end of Dwapara Yug.

[image]

But then that would mean there are 71 maha-yugs for every cycle of ice age ?
[image]

Comment: Scientific speculation is off-topic. Visit [this meta post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/142/3500).

Comment: That link is for "Users asking for scientific answers". 
There is no rule against trying to link Vedic Cosmology with Geologic changes.

Answer (score 0):

Yuga's are counted in Divine Years. Anything Divine is within you. The basis of time starts with a breathe and ends when there is no breathe as far as a human life is concerned.  If the divine within you is strong you live longer otherwise it is not so.  The concept of Yuga is clearly explained by Bhishma Pitamahan in his discussion with Yudhistra and also by Sri Krishna  before the war. Generally I see people in this forum commenting on all kind of concepts without any grounding in Jyotish. Jyotish is the eye of the Vedas. 99% of Vedas is Jyotish. The Itihaas and Puranas are a way of putting a context into jyotish for learning. When people read and interpret  Itihaas and Puranas without studying Jyotish we end up creating more perception than reality. The planetary motion decides the yuga and can change from time to time and at the time scale specified for the specific type of being. People who understand Jyotish will get this point.

Bhishma's quote below from SECTION CXLI of Mahabharata:

> "Bhishma said, 'O mighty-armed one, the peace and prosperity of
>   subjects,[425] sufficiency and seasonableness of rain, disease, death
>   and other fears, are all dependent on the king.[426] I have no doubt
>   also in this. O bull of Bharata's race, that Krita, Treta, Dwapara,
>   and Kali, as regards their setting in, are all dependent on the king's
>   conduct.When such a season of misery as has been described by thee
>   sets in, the righteous should support life by the aid of judgment. In
>   this connection is cited the old story of the discourse between
>   Viswamitra and the Chandala in a hamlet inhabited by Chandalas.
>   Towards the end of Treta and the beginning of Dwapara, a frightful
>   drought occurred, extending over twelve years, in consequence of what
>   the gods had ordained. At that time which was the end of Treta and the
>   commencement of Dwapara, when the period came for many creatures
>   superannuated by age to lay down p. 315 their lives, the thousand-eyed
>   deity of heaven poured no rain. The planet Vrihaspati began to move in
>   a retrograde course, and Soma abandoning his own orbit, receded
>   towards the south.