# Why does Adi Shankaracharya think Rig Veda 10.71.3 verse implies the Vedas are eternal?

Tags: vedas, brahma-sutras, rig-veda, adi-shankaracharya, brihaspati

As I discuss in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3193/36), by far the most popular school of Hindu philosophy is the Vedanta school, which bases its tenets on the doctrines laid out in the Brahma Sutras, a work by the sage Vyasa that summarizes and systematizes the philosophical teachings of the Upanishads. (You can read the Brahma Sutras [here](http://www.advaita.it/library/brahmasutras2.htm).)    In any case, in Adhyaya 1 Pada 3 of the Brahma Sutras, Vyasa discuss the issue of who is eligible for Jnana.  As I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8682/36), he says that low-caste people are not eligible for Jnana, since they don't wear the sacred thread.  But before that, he says that the gods *are* eligible for Jnana.

And that leads him into a discussion of the gods in general, in particular regarding how the Vedas can be eternal if mention the names of gods who do not remain in their positions forever.  As I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10352/36), the resolution is that the same names recur in different ages.  But in his commentary on [Adhyaya 1 Pada 3 Sutra 29](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe34/sbe34098.htm) of his commentary on the Brahma Sutras, Adi Shankaracharya gives a few other arguments for the Vedas being eternal:

> [T]he eternity of the Veda is founded on the absence of the remembrance of an agent only.... The eternity of the word of the Veda has to be assumed for this very reason, that the world with its definite (eternal) species, such as gods and so on, originates from it.--**A mantra also ('By means of the sacrifice they followed the trace of speech; they found it dwelling in the rishis,' Rig-veda Samh. X, 71, 3) shows that the speech found (by the rishis) was permanent.**--On this point Vedavyâsa also speaks as follows: 'Formerly the great rishis, being allowed to do so by Svayambhû, obtained, through their penance, the Vedas together with the itihâsas, which had been hidden at the end of the yuga.'

I discuss the notion that the Vedas are a blueprint for the creation of the world in my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11793/36).  But my question is about the Rig Vedic verse that Adi Shankaracharya cites, which is verse 3 of [Book 10 Hymn 71](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe34/sbe34098.htm) of the Rig Veda:

> yajñena vācaḥ padavīyamāyan tāmanvavindannṛṣiṣupraviṣṭām | 
>   tāmābhṛtyā vyadadhuḥ purutrā tāṃ saptarebhā abhi saṃ navante ||
>
> With sacrifice the trace of Vāk they foIlowed, and found her harbouring within the Ṛṣis. 
>   They brought her, dealt her forth in many places: seven singers make her tones resound in concert.

As you can see in the Rig Veda Anukramani in my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2430/36), this verse was heard during Tapasya by Brihaspati, the guru of the gods, and the subject of the hymn is listed as "Jnanam".  But my question is, why does Adi Shankaracharya think that this verse proves that the Vedas are eternal?

The verse discusses how Vak, which as I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7082/36) is a name of Saraswati in her capacity as goddess of speech, was found by the wise as "harbouring within the Rishis." But why does that imply "that the speech found (by the rishis) was permanent"?  Is Adi Shankaracharya arguing that the fact that it says the speech was "found" within the rishis as opposed to "composed" by them implies that the Vedas don't have a human author?

Are there any commentaries on Adi Shankaracharya's Brahma Sutra Bhashya that shed light on this?

Comment: Is Badarayana Vyas who wrote Brahma Sutra the same Krishna Dwaipayana Vyas or different persons ?

Comment: @keshavsrinivasan: Could you point out the verse? I am confused: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv10073.htm

Comment: @Tezz Yes, Badarayana the author of the Brahma Sutras is the same as Krishna Dvaipayana Vedavyasa.

Comment: @AmitSaxena It's the third verse of this hymn: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv10071.htm

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: You mentioned 73 instead of 71 in the question. Also, the link does not take you to the Sanskrit Sloka.

Comment: @AmitSaxena Thanks, I fixed it.  And yeah, I linked to the English translation, but that page has a link to the Sanskrit.

Comment: I think it means that the Rishis are the revealers of the eternal Vedic speech.

Answer (score 4):

The  *Rishis*, from various places, gather every once in a while to meditate as is enunciated through the tradition of *Kumbha Mela.* In such a confluence, in deep group meditation, the *Rishis* of yore heard sounds or *mantras* (*Sruti*). This is before the advent of any language. These sounds were then used to formulate a language which came to be known as *Sanskrit*. Also, the sounds or the mantras heard were very recently compiled into *Vedas*, since *1500 BC*,. There was no written accounts before this and as is widely known this was an oral tradition. I reproduce my answer from [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8583/which-was-developed-first-sanskrit-or-vedas/11760#11760) to support this:

> Q: Guruji, why are all mantras in *Sanskrit*? What is so special about
> Sanskrit?
>
> Sri Sri Ravi Shankar: No, *Sanskrit* was derived later.
> *Mantras* were already there. The words of the *mantra* were already
> there; later on the languages was created. Not only in Sanskrit, but
> when you go deeper into all languages, you will find all these
> *mantras*.

Coming to the *Shloka*:

> यज्ञेन **वाचः** पदवीयमायन तामन्वविन्दन्न्र्षिषुप्रविष्टाम |
>
> तामाभ्र्त्या वयदधुः पुरुत्रा तां सप्तरेभा अभि सं नवन्ते ||

The word वाचः has multiples meanings. It means *voice, word, sound* amongst other things. (It does refer to *Goddess Saraswati* too, the Goddess of all sounds and speech). These meanings are taken from this [dictionary](https://archive.org/details/1872sanskriten00moniuoft).

The first part of the *Shloka*:

> यज्ञेन वाचः पदवीयमायन तामन्वविन्दन्न्र्षिषुप्रविष्टाम |
>
> With sacrifice the trace of *Vācha* they followed, and found her harbouring within the *Ṛiṣhis*.

Hence, *Adi Shankaracharya* says that when the sounds or *Vacha* were traced to their origin, they were found harboured in the *Rishis*. In other words, it is the *Rishis* who heard these sounds first in deep meditation.

Here is another [translation](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=SSammk5xUUEC&pg=PT47&lpg=PT47&dq=rigveda%2010%2071%203&source=bl&ots=BL_J9Q8yKS&sig=_Q1U0044_zR3IEbD4uOjjsjetwc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3jvuO5bvMAhUDPo4KHYJSCkUQ6AEIOjAF#v=onepage&q=rigveda%2010%2071%203&f=false) by *Prof. Shrikant Prasoon* to support this:

> The learned or the *Rishis* receive the meaning of the great words
> through their indulgence into *Yagna*. The words were revealed to and
> received by the heart of the essence-knowing *Rishis*. After receiving
> they popularised them. In this way they expressed them in the form of
> the prayers.

*Chronologically*, these sounds were later used, spread through oral means for a very long time, a language was developed on the same, the sounds were later compiled as texts (*Vedas*) around [1500 BC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Hindu_texts), and grammar of the language enunciated by *Panini* in his *Ashtadhyayi* which only happened around *[4th century BC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%81%E1%B9%87ini)*.

Hence, as *Adi Shankaracharya* says, the *Vedas* which are the *Srutis* as heard by the *Rishis* in deep meditation are eternal.

Comment: But what is there in the verse that indicates that the sounds that were found harboured in the Rishis were eternal?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: My understanding on this is that these are the sounds that resonate closest with the consciousness or Brahman. (Thats why they can be only heard in deep meditation). There are so many other sounds too but whose vibration is not as much in sync. Hence, as consciousness is said to be eternal, these sounds are the closest ones to be eternal.

Comment: Well, I for one certainly agree that the Vedas are eternal.  I just don't see why, from the perspective of someone who didn't believe that the Vedas were eternal, this particular verse would convince them that the Vedas are eternal.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: It is quite evident to me. I am not sure what point you are missing. I think this Shloka is chronologically very deep as it talks about tracing all speech back to the Rishis which is a very very long process. Once that link is established, it inherently implies that the sounds closest to the Brahman are closest to being eternal.

Comment: Well, the verse doesn't actually say that the sounds found harboured in the Rishis are sounds that are closest to Brahman or anything like that.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: Yes, I agree with that. I think it is inherently assumed, although that is only my viewpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Adi Sankara says, the verse maintains that Rishis just fine-tuned themselves (like in meditation) to arrive at Vedic hymns, which proves (through Sabda pramANa) that hymns were already existing contrary to be authored by them. Another translation of the Rik verse is as follows -

> By means of their past good deeds (the priests) **attained the capacity to understand the Vedas;** then they found them dwelling in the Rishis. RV-10.71.3

As an analogy, Sounds coming forth from Radios is akin to Vedic hymns coming forth from Rishis. Likewise, Sounds existing independently from Radios in the form of electromagnetic waves in the sky is akin to Vedic hymns existing independently from Rishis in form of VAk (speech). As sounds coming forth from Radio doesn't make radio to be the author of the sounds, so coming forth of hymns through Rishis don't make them the author of the Vedas (or Vedic hymns).

Btw, [SphoTa-vAd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spho%E1%B9%ADa) might explain it more rigorously.