# Why should i believe in vedas? Any scientific proof for the same?

Tags: vedas, science

Someone who has read Vedas, please answer these questions to strengthen the belief of any person in Vedas.

Is there anything written in Vedas which seems to be non-evident to common sense/is otherwise non-trivial and thus requires higher consciousness to be aware of?

In other words any fact which ancient people would not not be able to know in those times by ordinary means  but are written in Vedas and have been proven by modern science eg. something like sun being the center of solar system or age of universe or something of this sort?

Thanks in advance.

[The question is not duplicate of the below mentioned one as I am specifically asking facts written in Vedas not a general proof based on logic as given in that answer. Please provide facts which seem to be known only via supernatural powers but are written in Vedas. So please remove duplicate tag.]

Comment: Note that scientific speculation is considered [off-topic](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/121/277).

Comment: I think this question answers your question. [What is the validity of Authoritativeness of vedas?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14755/3500) and can be possible duplicate.

Comment: Purva Mimamsa Sutras are best place to find answer for this with logical arguments.

Comment: If you are asking for scientific reason without "Logic", then the question is offtopic for this site.

Comment: You may be interested in this question [What are some scientific facts described in Hindu scriptures?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17442/3500)

Comment: In the title you ask for scientific proof; in the body you ask for references to the supra-physical which by definition are unprovable by science. What are you asking? "Why must I believe in the vedas" is a matter of faith. No amount of reasoning will help if basic faith and respect for the veda is missing. The only way to gain this faith is to have grace descend on us in some form or the other.

Comment: @moonstar2001 It is possible to prove the Pramanya and Apaurusheyatva of the Vedas to someone who has no faith using the arguments given in Adhyaya 1 Pada 1 of the Purva Mimamaa Sutras.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan dharma jignyAsa?

Comment: @moonstar2001 both in body and title I am asking something which would have been otherwise impossible in those times to be known by means available at those times, but  is now proven scientifically using modern innovations. For example, speed of light would have been impossible to be measured without sophisticated instruments ao if Vedas tell about speed of light that would make anyone atleast believe that Vedas were beyond human knowledge of those times and thus apurusheya.

Comment: Other example would be yog, which has cured numerous diseases of mankind and multiple proofs have been documented using scientific means to remove any doubt/suspicion of it being truly effective rather than a blind faith/superstition and the whole world is now following yog day on 21st June.

Comment: So based on these lines, I believe there should also exist some proof to prove beyond doubt that Vedas are apurusheya.

Comment: Please remove duplicate tag, I sincerely again urge. This is different question than the mentioned one. Also there does not exist any very well accepted answer in that question. Just for some time please remove the duplicate tag. @TheDestroyer.

Comment: @rastplyr Title sounds offtopic. We don't want anyone to speculate here in name of science. If you want to know Scientific facts mentioned in Vedas,like speed of light as mentioned by Sayanacharya, you see this question. [What are some scientific facts described in Hindu scriptures?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17442/3500).