# Which is the clearest verse from the vedas that say "vedas are eternal"?

Tags: vedas

Which is the clearest verse from the vedas that clearly say vedas are eternal?

Comment: you want the citation from the Samhitas themselves?  is https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27658/where-do-purva-and-uttara-mimamsa-sutras-claim-that-vedas-are-eternal?rq=1 sufficient? @dark knight

Comment: @SK well the answer should be only from vedas. And it doesn't look like it is from the vedas (the link)

Comment: I'm very confused about the term "clearest verse". What does it connotes?

Comment: @Vivikta means that it should say the some thing like this  "Vedas are eternal".  By clearest verse I also mean which is easy to understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17831/are-there-any-mantra-or-mantras-in-veda-samhitas-that-confirm-that-vedas-are-apa

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any mantra or mantras in Veda Samhitas that confirm that Vedas are apaurusheya?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17831/are-there-any-mantra-or-mantras-in-veda-samhitas-that-confirm-that-vedas-are-apa)