# Why are Vedas regarded as Apaurusheya (authorless/ not created by anyone)?

Tags: vedas, philosophy, dharma, sin

Why are Vedas regarded as [Apaurusheya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apauru%E1%B9%A3ey%C4%81) (authorless/ not created by anyone)?

Is it a sin to consider that Veda was written by someone as propagated by Western scholars?

Comment: Related or Duplicate: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17831/are-there-any-mantra-or-mantras-in-veda-samhitas-that-confirm-that-vedas-are-apa

Comment: Vedas were given to Rishis by isvara who did intense tapasya.

Comment: is it a sin to consider or belive that veda created by someone because in some of the question there were answer regarding assining of dates for vedic scriptures

Comment: @Rickross i think its duplicate may be delete

Comment: @prasanna, what is sin? Sin is that which is against Dharma, and Dharma is what is outlined by Hari the essence of which is in our scriptures. Ultimately Hari decides what is sin based on his own judgment. Scriptures are guiding principles but they are not hard rocks. The judge always considers the situations. This is my opinion.

Comment: @Subashrajaa correct the last line in your answer is the answer for the question good, knowingly or unknowingly your antrayami had answered its is sin, because the whole idea of assign date and creator is malicious and propagated by westerners unfortunately our people cut copy paste this intent and further do propagation

Comment: No ur Q is also asking abt whether to consider Vedas having author a sin or not.. so it's different slightly @prasannaragothaman

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per Brihadaranyaka Upanishad, not just Vedas but all our scriptures are the breath of the supreme being.

Yajnavalkya Maharaja tells Maitreyi Devi,

> As from a fire kindled with wet fuel various kinds of smoke issue forth, even so, my dear, the Rig—Veda, the Yajur—Veda, the Sama—Veda, the Atharvangirasa, history (itihasa), ancient transmissions (purana), the arts (vidya), the Upanishads, verses (slokas), aphorisms (sutras), elucidations (anuvyakhyanas) and explanations (vyakhyanas) are like the breath of this infinite Reality. From this Supreme Self are all these, indeed, breathed forth.

The logic is just like a breath of a person is coexistent with a person, the Vedas are coexistent with Ishvara and not created at any point.

Answer (score 1):

> The word Rishi means a seer (from *dris*, to see). He is the Mantra-Drashta, a seer of Mantra ,which was not his own. The Rishis saw the truths or heard them. Therefore, the Vedas are what are heard (Sruti).  He **did not create it out of his mind.** He was only the spiritual discoverer . He is not the inventor of the Veda. The Rishi is only a medium or an agent to transmit to people the intuitional experiences which he received. The truths of the Vedas are revelations, that do not owe their authority to any one. They are themselves the authority as they are eternal, being the Knowledge of the Lord.Lord Brahma, the Creator, imparted the divine knowledge to the Rishis or seers. The Rishis disseminated the knowledge. The Vedic Rishis were great realised persons who had direct intuitive perception of Brahman or the Truth.
> All About Hinduism , Chapter 2, Swami Sivananda

> The sounds we produce are never destroyed. I remember reading that what Jesus Christ spoke 2, 000 years ago could still be recaptured in his own voice and that efforts are being made for the same. I don't know how far these efforts have succeeded. But I do know that there does exist such a possibility (of receiving a voice or sound from the past). We know that a sound, once it is produced, remains in space without ever being destroyed.
> Brahma created this world with the sound of the Vedas and this sound is not destroyed even during a great deluge.Brahma saw the sounds corresponding to these vibrations as the Vedas and the chanted them and brought all the world into existence.Brahma could create the universe with the sound of the Vedas because of his power of concentration. A siddha can cure a sick man if he intones the Pancakasara mantra - the mantra that we mutter every day - and applies holy ashes to the patient's body. He is able to do it because he has greater power of concentration .Brahma, the Creator, alone knows the Vedas in their entirety. We cannot claim that all the Vedas have been revealed to the seers. Only about a thousand sakhas or recensions belonging to the four Vedas have been revealed to them.
>
> Hindu dharma, the universal way of Life. Pujyasri Chandrashekhara Saraswati Swami