# Is the pranava - om - mentioned in Vedas?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, om

The [Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om#Origin_and_meaning), in respect of the syllable **om**,  as follows:

> The syllable Om is **first mentioned** in the Upanishads, the mystical
>   texts associated with the Vedanta philosophy.

[Rig veda 1.164.39](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv01164.htm) says as follows:

> रचो अक्षरे परमे वयोमन यस्मिन देवा अधि विश्वे निषेदुः |
>    यस्तन न वेद किं रचा करिष्यति य इत तद विदुस्त इमे समासते ||
>
> ṛco akṣare parame vyoman yasmin devā adhi viśve niṣeduḥ |
>    yastan na veda kiṃ ṛcā kariṣyati ya it tad vidusta ime samāsate ||
>
> The vedas rest in the **imperishable syllable** in the Supreme ether (of the heart).  Those who do not know that, what can they do with the veda?  Those who know that are gathered here

Can we infer from the above mantra from Rig Veda, that अक्षरे - **imperishable syllable** indicates **Om**?

Comment: The Rig Vedic mantra is not talking about Om.

Comment: @Rickross: My doubt is about indirect reference of om - imperishable syllable - akshara

Comment: No it is not. It is talking about Ricah akashara or Rik mantras being situated in the ether. Because of the translation you've used you are probably getting that feeling. You can see another translation here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18501

Comment: @Rickross: I agree that there can be different translations.  do you want to say the translation that I quoted is wrong/not dependable?

Comment: No I can not say that it is wrong. But I feel the one that I used is more appropriate.

Comment: For example in another question you've used a translation where they translated "chandamsi" to "charms and spells". I am not sure on what basis they did that.

Comment: @Rickross:I am giving links to 2 sites. Please check.(http://www.meluhha.com/rv/verse.pl?v=01.164.39&acc=no&q=gop&lang=ved) -( https://slideplayer.com/slide/7634863/)

Comment: Ok I have seen both. I am not in favor of saying that it is talking about Om here because I consider the translation that I have used in my answer as the appropriate one. Although I am not sure if anywhere else in the Vedas they have mentioned about Om or not. It can be that it is mentioned. My guess is in the Yajurvedas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97330/discussion-between-srimannarayana-k-v-and-rickross).

Comment: The Upanishads are part and parcel of the vedas. The Wikipedia article you reference makes it appear that the Upanishads are separate from the vedas - they are not! Vyasa partitioned part of the vedas off into the Upanishads, they are not later or separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ऋचो  अक्षरे परमे व्योमन यस्मिन देवा अधि विश्वे निषेदुः | 
यस्तन्न  वेद किमृचा करिष्यति य इत्तद्विदुस्त इमे समासते || RV .1.164.39 ||

This Rishi of this Mantra is Dirghatamas and is Known as "Asya Vamiya Sukta " . The Mantras 1-41 are dedicated to Vishwadeva.

In this  Mantra  Dirghatamas  is pointing towards those who do not know the Imperishable Brahman.Rishi Dirghatamas Is also saying that  what use the Vedas would be to a person who does not know the characteristics of Brahman because  Vedas are a in the  Brahman, who is like space and never changing. All the gods rest in Brahman. If a person knows nothing about Brahman but only performs rituals and rites what will he gain? On the opposite  those who know Brahman, as it were, live like as they are one with Brahman and attain Bliss .

This Sukta is Of type VedaGyana -Prashansa i.e. in praise of Knowledge in the  Vedas .The manta 39 of which speaks of the syllable ( akshara ) that exists in the divine.  Here in this mantra the word Richas ऋचा is to be taken as all the  Vedas.

---

Let's first of all see what the western as well as Indian translators has translated the mantra.

[**H.H.Wilson**](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.41621/page/n171) with Commentary of Sayana

> All the gods have taken their seats up this supreme heaven , the
>   imperishable (text) of the veda : What will he , who knows not this ,
>   do with the veda ? but they who know it , they are perfect.

---

[**Pandit Shriram Sharma Acharya**](http://literature.awgp.org/book/rigveda/v2.137) - AWGP

> Indestructible Richa's (vedas) are contained in supreme Vyoma (i.e. 
>   Vast Akasha ) , all godly powers resides in that. What Richa's (vedas)
>   do for him who do not know this truth , those who know this truth do
>   make a good use of this Richa's (vedas) .

---

Rigved Subodh Bhashya by [**Satavalekar Damodar**](https://archive.org/details/HindiBookRigvedSubodhBhashyaHindiPart1/page/n443)

> The Paramatma is like the Vast  space  and indestructible like
>   aksharas of vedas. All the gods resides in that Paramatma. Who does
>   not know this Parabrahman ,what they will do with these Veda mantras.
>   Those learned  who knows this Param-Tatva , dwells in the higher
>   places

---

---

This same Rig -Veda manta is also found in **Atharva Veda 9.10.18** and     in The [**Shvetashvatara Upanishad 4.8**](https://archive.org/details/SvetasvataraUpanishadSwamiGambhiranandaR.K.Mutt/page/n169)  We are having a good commentary of Shree Adi Shankaracharya on same mantra in the Shvetashvatara Upanishad . Lets see what he is saying.

ऋचो अक्षरे परमे व्योमन् यस्मिन्देवा अधि विश्वे निषेदु : |
यस्तं न वेद किमृचा कारिष्यति य इत्तद्विदुस्त इमे समासते ||4.8 ||

> 8 The vedas are established on the imperishable supreme space where
>   all the gods dwell . What will one achieve through the Vedas , who
>   does not know it . thus they who are such , remain self-fulfilled.
>
> Shankara's Commentary - :
>
> Rcah the Vedas ; are established aksare , in the imperishable ; Parame
>   , supreme  : Vyoman (i.e. vyomni) , space - comparable to space - ,
>   which is known from the three vedas  ; and yasmin , where  ; visve
>   devah , all the gods  ; adhiniseduh , dwell , stay supported . Kim
>   karishyati , what will one achieve ; rca through the vedas ; yah , who
>   ; na veda , does not know ; tam , it? ye , those who ; viduh , khow ;
>   tat ; it , thus ; te they ; are such ; samste , remain self fulfilled.
>
> ---
>
> Now as of your enquiry  is this अक्षरे - imperishable syllable indicates Om?

From looking at all the translations above  ,it is clear that none of them supportive to the notion that  this Aksara here is denoting  sacred letter  "OM".  Adi Shankara in his commentary is saying that the Aksharas of vedas are residing in that Parabrahman , who is supreme and vast like the space.

Shree Satavalekar is also explaining that this Akshras of  Richas (vedas) are  like that of Paramatma who is also  indestructible.

And  also  according to Very well known vedic scholar  [**Shree Siddheshwar  Shastri Chitrav**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siddheshwar_Shastri_Chitrav) , the notion of Akshara is presented as Atma or Parmatma only in his commentary of this mantra which is in Marathi. i am enclosing a screenshot of it below.

---

The Only exception is Yaskacharya Sanskrit grammarian (4th c. BCE ) whose views are mentioned in this [**Shodhganga**](https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/142957/8/08_chapter%202.pdf) Article (PDF ) -Page 35.

> That this Aksara" is "Om" .  Of the phrase " rco akshare parame
>   vyoman," found in the above hymn,' Yaska in his Niruktd has an
>   enlightening explanation.According to him "Aksara" is "Om" on which
>   all the gods repose. 'Those who do not know this Supreme Word; what
>   can they do with 'rcah' only, and those who know it are, well placed'-
>   is the advice of the learned.
>
> What is that word - “aksara” ? Yaska says “ It is "Om", in the
>   opinion of Sakapuni”.43 (Sakapuni” was an ancient Grammarian).44
>   Therefore, here, 'Om' is the Ultimate Reality ('Brahman') on which
>   everything, (including Vak) rests

So here we see the two sides one side is all the available translators and on the other  Sanskrit grammarians "Yaska"  who is saying this on the opinion of  Sakapuni a another ancient Grammarian that Aksara" . is "Om"

In this case coming to  any conclusion is tricky part.
But in conclusion -  Considering  central meaning of all the  current translations and seeing that none of them is supportive to this notion that word Aksara  is denoting "OM"  , and  mainly taking the help of Adi Shankara's expanaton.  The word Aksara here , which are akshara's of Vedas are equated with ParamAtma in this manta , and is pointing towards supreme Brahman . **So  we can safely say that  there is very faint possibility that this अक्षरे - imperishable syllable here  indicates Sacred letter "OM".**

---

[image]

Comment: I am coming to conclusion mainly with the support of commentary of Adi Shankara on the same mantra found in Shvetashvatara Upanishad. The difficulty here in explaining in answer  is the different translations by different authors. But the core message of all are same. So it is quite possible that the answer might look like much non explanatory. Adi shankara's commentary  mostly makes it clear ,and he is not also mentioning OM in that.

Comment: You have forgotten as to what is there in continuation to the article in the link - Even Upanisads, persued their enquiry on the basis the above propositions, and stated that ‘Om ’tself denotes the Ultimate Reality”. Taittkiya Upanisad declares that “Om is Brahman;Om is this all’(‘Omiti Brahma,Omiti dam sarvam’  Anyways, Thanks once again.@SwiftPushkar.

Comment: In your answer you had stated that word Richas ऋचा is to be taken as all the Vedas. In Purusha Sukta R.V .- 10.90.9 , apart from Richas,  sama and yaju were also mentioned.  Can you explain why it was so?@SwiftPushkar

Comment: Thanks for explaining the issue, duly narrating arguments from both sides :-). If we leave aside modern commentators, we will be left with Sri Sankara and Sri Yaska. However,  a Wikipedia article says that
Shvetashvatara Upanishad was not authored by Sri Sankara   :-)@SwiftPushkar.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Om is mentioned in the Veda Samhitas. It first occurs in Yajur Veda.

> The butter's rapid flow delight his spirit! Brihaspati extend this act
>   of worship. May he restore the sacrifice uninjured. Here let all Gods
>   rejoice. **OM!** Step thou forward. (Shukla Yajur Veda 2.13).

---

Pranava is also mentioned in Isha Upanishad, i.e, Shukla Yajur Veda 40:

> My breath reach everlasting Air! In ashes let my body end. **OM!** Mind,
>   remember thou; remember thou my sphere; remember thou my deeds.(15)
>
> The Real's face is hidden by a vessel formed of golden light. The
>   Spirit yonder in the Sun, the Spirit dwelling there am I. **OM!** Heaven!
>   Brahma!(17)

---

Comment: can you post sanskrit text as well for more clarity please?@Spark Sunshine

Comment: @srimannarayanakv I will add later.