# Do people get specific mantras for them through meditation?

Tags: mantras, meditation

I was wondering if people can get personal mantras from meditation.

Comment: I do not even understand what the question is :O

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik When people are meditating do people get personal mantras like how the rishis got mantras from meditation and wrote them down.

Comment: As far as I know, you meditate, with a mantra, when you are given the mantra by some one. It is usually the one who practiced it pass on to others. You can create new mantra but the question is if it is of any use..

Comment: I think its possible. @Ria The question makes perfect sense to me ... It may happen but very rarely. Something similar is getting mantras in dreams.. that is also counted as a type of Diksha

Comment: Most likely possible, If not we can not have so many mantras. But this may not easy to get one by an ordinary individual like us (me). A Mantra is a repeated word or phrase, prayer or chant, that can be used as a form of relaxation or meditation. An example of a mantra is a team saying "We will win" over and over again then final them Won. Each mantra has different effects, it totally depends on thoughts, feelings, words, and actions impact your consciousness.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How did Rishis perform Tapasya (transcendental meditation) so that they heard Shruti/Veda?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17831/3500)