# Do the Vedas say they are eternal?

Tags: scripture, vedas, vedanta, pramana, apaurusheyatva

Many Hindu theologians, especially those of the Vedanta school, believe that not just the meaning, but the very words and sentences of the Vedas are eternal. Is there any support in the Vedas themselves for this view?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any mantra or mantras in Veda Samhitas that confirm that Vedas are apaurusheya?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17831/are-there-any-mantra-or-mantras-in-veda-samhitas-that-confirm-that-vedas-are-apa)