# Is Bhakti is part of Upasana or It is connected with any of the Darshana?

Tags: vedas, bhakti, shad-darshana, upasana

This verse of the Srimad-Bhagavatam is very popular and a favorite of the Advaita Acharyas:

योगास्त्रयो मया प्रोक्ता न्èणां श्रेयोविधित्सया ।
ज्ञानं कर्म च भक्तिश्च नोपायोऽन्योऽस्ति कुत्रचित॥ (११.२०.६)

Lord Krishna said: My dear Uddhava http://vedabase.net/u/uddhava, because I desire that human beings may achieve perfection, I have presented three paths of advancement — the path of knowledge, the path of work and the path of devotion. Besides these three there is absolutely no other means of elevation.

My question is, is the Bhakti (one of the three paths of advancement) can be concluded under one of the Upasana (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upasana), which is one of the three-part of Vedas along with Aranyakas and Upanishads?

oR the bhakti is more related to one of the Darshana (Hindu Philosphy)? (for example part of Vedanta -> and Shudd Advaita or dvaita etc)

Comment: Many may not agree with this but, Bhakti is a type of yoga like Karma Yoga, etc. So it’s not Found in the Vedas but is definitely in accordance with the Vedas. Veda, Purāṇa, Agama, Sankhya, Yoga. It’s one of the yogas in this category

Comment: Yes right about "Bhakti Yoga" part , also this question suggests that there are reference of "Bhakti" in Vedas  https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7230/what-are-the-earliest-references-to-bhakti-yoga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen this claim that Upasana is a division of the Vedas.

> As such, they [Vedas] are divided into **four major parts**, and each of
> these, in turn, is further divided - as may be conveniently seen in
> the following table:
>
> Work [karma kanda] : Samhitas, Brahmanas, Aranyakas;
>
> Knowledge [Jnana]: Upanishads;

**The Spiritual Heritage of India by Swami Prabhavananda**

**Bhakti is recommended in the Upanishad part of the Vedas.**

> Mental activities relative to the Saguna Brahman - such as are
> described in the Shandilya Vidya are **Upasanas or devotions**.

**Vedantasara 12 of Sadananda Yogindra**

**So where is Shandilya Vidya?**

It is in **Chandogya Upanishad**.

> Verily, all this universe is Brahman. From Him do all things
> originate, into Him do they dissolve and by Him are they sustained. **On
> Him should one meditate in tranquility.** For as is one's faith in this
> world, such one becomes on departing hence. Let one, therefore,
> cultivate faith.

**Chandogya Upanishad 3.14.1**

The bolded mantra [santa upashita] in the above Chandogya shloka is considered by Sri Yogindra as Upanishadic support for Bhakti marga.

Bhakti marga is accepted by all the major Vedantic schools including Advaita Vedanta. Bhakti plays a major role in Vedanta Darsana.