# Why each word of Srimad Bhagavad Gita is considered to be so important?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, vyasa, gita

Bhagavad Gita was compiled by Vyasadeva ('Vyasena grathitam') in the anustubh and indrabajra/upendrabajra metres. To convert the conversations into such metres, He surely had to change or add words to maintain the rigid structures of these metres. Why is it then that each and every word captioned 'Sri Bhagavan uvacha' is taken by the great acharya as the utterance of Lord Krishna Himself?

Why are all the Gitas streelingavachaka, i.e none is named as Giah or Gitam?

Comment: You are asking too many questions under a single question. Limit your question to a single question and ask only one per a post. First question is already asked [Why is Bhagavad Gita of Lord Krishna considered as the ultimate Gita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7911/5212) and there was also another question which I can't find the link. So, remove that part from the question and focus on a single question.

Comment: We do not repeat the same questions or answers here. Answers which explain the superiority will go to that question because it was asked first.  If many questions are asked in the same question, it will get closed as too broad. So, remove first question.

Comment: Title doesn't match with is asked in the body. Looks like a Sanskrit-related question. So not sure why you need all those tags.

Comment: There are enough words in the Sanskrit language to find the right ones to convey the proper meaning in any given meter.

Comment: @sv. The initial question was why is it considered superior. The title was written to reflect that. Then due to suggestion, that's removed from the body but title is not changed. The title should be modified to reflect the body.

Comment: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/bhagavad-gita-mahatmya/d/doc81421.html

Comment: @Mr.P Kindly dont refer to puranic descriptions.i prefer the sayings of saints.regards