# What scripture says "the soul is neither God nor man"?

Tags: philosophy, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, atma, vedanta-desika

The Rahasyatraya Sara is a work by the Sri Vaishnava Acharya Vedanta Desikan, concerning the meaning of the [Rahasya Traya](http://www.srivaishnavan.com/faqs/ans_secrets.php) or three secrets of the Sri Vaishnava sect (of which I'm a member). (One of these secrets is the Dvaya mantra used to surrender to Vishnu, which I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7971/36).) In [this excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCHnw.jpg) from the Rahasyatraya Sara, Vedanta Desikan discusses how the Jiva benefits from having a guru:

> His gurus reveal to the Jiva the intimate relation existing between him and Narayana, the Lord of Lakshmi, who rules with his scepter the earth surrounded by the turbulent ocean and the world of Vaikunta without even the least exception.  Do not the shastras say **"The soul is neither God nor man, neither beast nor tree.  Its essential nature is knowledge and bliss and it is entirely dependent on the Supreme Being and exists solely for his purposes (Sesha)"** and again "The souls are indeed servants by nature of the supreme Supreme Being"?

The second quote is from verse 11 of the [Mantra Raja Pada Stotram](http://murpriya.blogspot.com/2010/09/mantra-raja-patha-stotram-with-meening.html), a hymn to Narasimha from a Pancharatra text called the Ahirbudhnya Samhita.  (See my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6896/36) for more information on the Pancharatra texts.)

But my question is, what scripture does the first quote come from, the one which says "The soul is neither God nor man..."?  It seems like an interesting quote, so I'd like to see the passage it's from.

Are there any commentaries on Vedanta Desikan's work who address this?

Comment: I dont know, which scripture Desikar refers to , but what i understand is that Soul is not the body i.e  beast, man god or tree. Desikar seems to echoing the BG verses which indicate the soul is different from the body..Its essential nature is Knowledge and bliss which is covered by endless karmas.

Comment: @Krishna I'm more interested in the end of the quote, which uses the term Sesha to denote the soul's relation to Vishnu; that's why I want to know what scripture it's from.  By the way, I just posted another question on the Rahasyatraya Sara: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8293/36

Comment: RTS has to be learnt at the feet of an bonafide acharya. We can search for info in RTS but, if one really needs to learn the essence and all, one has to go through proper process of learning the secrets from an acharyan only.

Comment: @Krishna Well, I'm not really expecting to get that deep of an understanding from the questions I'm posting on the Rahasyatraya Sara.  I'm just trying to get some basic information.