# Are there incarnations of humans. Devas et al as inanimate entities in canonical Sanskrit scripture?

Tags: avatars

South Indian Srivaishnavite scripture records that the Srivaishnavite guru Vedanta Desikan is an incarnation of the bell at the Tirupati Venkateshwara temple::

[https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/what-is-the-earliest-reference-to-vedanta-desikan-being-an-incarnation-of-venkat#:~:text=In%20any%20case%2C%20Sri%20Vaishnavas,Tirumala%20Venkateshwara%20temple%20in%20Tirupati](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/what-is-the-earliest-reference-to-vedanta-desikan-being-an-incarnation-of-venkat#:%7E:text=In%20any%20case%2C%20Sri%20Vaishnavas,Tirumala%20Venkateshwara%20temple%20in%20Tirupati).

In Canonical Sanskrit literature, Ahalya is turned into a stone due to a curse.

But are there instances in Canonical literature of a human or Deva or God incarnating as an inanimate object?