# What exactly are Pancharatra texts?

Tags: vaishnavism, pancharatra, vishnu

One of the early movements that was important to the development of Vaishnavism was the ancient Pancharatra movement, whose sacred texts or Agamas consisted of detailed procedures to worship the sage Narayana, an ancient incarnation of Vishnu. Since the Pancharatra Agamas originated from Narayana himself, they're followed by pretty much all mainstream Vaishnavas today.

The first time I came across the word '*Pancharatra*' was in case of Narada Pancharatra.

Every subsequent time I came across this word I thought Pancharatra refers to Narada Pancharatra. Basically, I had this idea that there is one scripture; Narada Pancharatra just like any other scripture.

As I went through different questions on this site and [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancharatra); I realised that Pancharatra is not a single scripture.

So the question is;

1. What are the different Pancharatra texts (I read that there are around 200 of them); please mention the principal ones.
2. What is the basis to classify a text as a Pancharatra text?
   Ex. Bhagavad-Geeta is classified as Pancharatra text. What could be the reason to refer Geeta as a Pancharatra text?

Comment: See my answer here for more information on Pancharatra: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6896/36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan can you please give me the link to English translation of Narada Pancaratra.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**What is Pancharatra**

> Pancharatra texts are Vaishnava Agama Shastras, the name pancharatra literally means 'five nights', since these scriptures were revealed by [Sage Narayana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nara-Narayana)
>   in 5 Nights to all the Rishis. Sage Narayana was so generous to us humans that he preserved ancient Ekayana shakha of Shukla Yajurveda and created agamas out of it so that everybody irrespective of caste creed sexuality could worship Shriman Naryana, and realize the truth that he is the Supreme Being.

-- [As quoted in wiki - Pancharatra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancharatra)

[**List of Pancharatra texts**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancharatra#Pancharatra_Texts)

The Yoga knowledge that Shri Krishna talks about is addressed in Chapter 4 of Shrimad Bhagwad Gita [Here is relevant disscussion](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8795/why-wasnt-bhagavad-gita-available-at-the-time-of-ramayana), how it was transfered from Him(Shriman Narayana) to Lord Bramha & so on.

The knowledge he is talking about is of Panchartara tradition . Bhishma taught this knowledge to Yudhishtira [Shanti Parva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanti_Parva) of Mahabharata
[Chronology of Shrimad Bhagwad Gita](http://www.bhagavad-gita.org/Articles/vyasa.html)

Comment: Bhishma teaches Yudhishthira about Pancharatra in the Shanti Parva, not the Anushasana Parva.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, Yogi: In which scripture is the incident of Sage Narayana giving knowledge in 5 nights is mentioned? Would be helpful to also know the specific verses or texts if possible. Thank you.

Comment: @PrakashK The five-night Yagna performed by sage Narayana is mentioned in the Shatapatha Brahmana of the Yajur Veda; see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6896/36  The fact that this is when the Pancharatra Agamas were revealed is recorded in the Pancharatra Agamas themselves.  Further history of how the Pancharatra Agamas were passed down in different ages is given in the Shanti Parva of the Mahabharata.

Answer (score 3):

According to tradition, there are 108 Vaiṣṇava Pāñcarātra texts. However, there are more than 200 texts. These are also known as Saṁhitās. Here is the list of printed texts of the Pāñcarātrāgama.

1. Agastya Saṁhitā
2. Aniruddha Saṁhitā
3. Ahirbudhnya Saṁhitā
4. Iśvara Saṁhitā
5. Kapiñjala Saṁhitā
6. Kāśyapa Saṁhitā
7. Jayākhya Saṁhitā
8. Jñānāmṛtasāra Saṁhitā or Nārada Pāncarātra
9. Nāradīya Saṁhitā
10. Parama Saṁhitā
11. Paramapuruṣa Saṁhitā
12. Parāśara Saṁhitā
13. Pādma Saṁhitā or Pādma Tantra
14. Pārameśvara Saṁhitā
15. Puruṣottama Saṁhitā
16. Pauṣkara Saṁhitā
17. Bṛhad Brahma Saṁhitā
18. Bhāradvāja Saṁhitā
19. Mārkaṇḍeya Saṁhitā
20. Lakṣmī Tantra
21. Viśvāmitra Saṁhitā
22. Viṣṇu Saṁhitā
23. Viṣṇutilaka Saṁhitā
24. Viṣvaksena Saṁhitā
25. Sāṇḍilya Saṁhitā
26. Śeṣa Saṁhitā
27. Śrīpraśna Saṁhitā
28. Sanatkumāra Saṁhitā
29. Sāttvata Saṁhitā
30. Hayaśīrṣa Saṁhitā

**Source:** A descriptive bibliography of the printed texts of the Pāñcarātrāgama by H. Daniel Smith