# What is the Yogeshwara form of God Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, scripture, bhagavad-gita

> यत्र योगेश्वर: कृष्णो यत्र पार्थो धनुर्धर: |
>
> तत्र श्रीर्विजयो भूतिध्रुवा नीतिर्मतिर्मम || 78||
>
> BG 18.78

### Translation

> Wherever there is Shree Krishna, the Lord of all Yoga, and wherever there is Arjuna, the Supreme archer, there will also certainly be unending opulence, victory, prosperity, and righteousness. Of this, I am certain.

The foregoing is the last sloka of the Bhagavad Gita and it conveyed-

> There can be only **One** verdict in this war—victory will always be on the side of God and his pure devotee, and so will goodness, supremacy, and abundance.

In the foregoing sloka God Vishnu{Sri Krishna} is referred in the Yogeshwara form.

God Vishnu is also referred in the Yogeshwara form in the following Canto of Srimad Bhagavatam,

SB 4.22.22:-

> Attachment for the Supreme can be increased by practicing devotional service, inquiring about the Supreme Personality of Godhead, applying bhakti-yoga in life, worshiping the Yogeśhwara, the Supreme Personality of Godhead, and by hearing and chanting about the glories of the Supreme Personality of Godhead. These actions are pious in themselves.

What is the Yogeshwara form of God Vishnu? Is there a story why God Vishnu is also referred as Yogeshwara? Explain in brief.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yogeshwara translates to Lord/Master of Yoga**.

Shri Krishna is known as Yogeshwara because, Shriman Narayana in the form/avatar of Shri Krishna revived ancient knowledge of Yoga viz Bhakti, Jnana, and Karma  which is part of [Pancharatra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/12321/489) tradition (Bhagwad gita is gist of Pancharatara) on the battlefield of Kurukshetra.

Following is Bhagwad Ramanujacharya's [commentary](http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-18-78/) on BG 18.78

> Wherever, Sri Krishna, **the Lord of Yoga**, and Arjuna the archer are, there abide forever prosperity, victory, wealth and righteous statesmanship - this is my firm conviction.

**Shri Krishna is Yogeshwara or Yogeshwara avatar of Shriman Narayana.**

Shri Krishna in BG 4.1-4.6 speaks about the ancient knowledge of Bhagwad Gita which was passed down from Vivasavan manu(Manu of current Manvantara).

Answer (score 3):

**There is no Yogeswara form of Sri Vishnu.** Vishnu Himself is the Yogeswara. Yogeswara means the One Who is the Highest/ Idol of all yogis or Who is the Supreme Yogi Himself.

The Vishnusahasranaama says:

> "Yogo **Yogovidaam Neta** Pradhana- Puruseswarah"

meaning that Vishnu is the Leader of all yogis.

A well-known dhyanamantra of Vishnu says:

> Lakshmikantam Kamala-Nayanam **Yogivir Dhyana-gamyam**

So He is both the Highest Yogi and Worshipped by the Yogis.

Sri Krishna in Gita has been called Yogeswara because He is One with Sri Vishnu as He has been repeatedly referred to as Vishnu. **He is NOT the Yogeswara incarnation or form of Vishnu.**