# How to offer Naivedyam to Shriman Narayana

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, food

Offering Food or Naivedyam/[Prasadam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prasad) is integral part of [Vaishnava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaishnavism) lifestyle. 
Majority of Vaishnavas follow [Pancharatra Agama shastras](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/12321/489), therefore I assume Naivedyam procedure is described in those texts.

So the question becomes :

What is the method(from Pancharatra texts) to offer Naivedyam to Shriman Narayana.

If there is a difference in Sri Vaishnava Naivedya procedure them please mention that in your answer.

Comment: You can this procedure followed in Sri Vaishnava temples at the time of offering naivedyam.  https://youtu.be/slp4atchVpw?t=1469