# Which Vaishnava Sects consider Vaishnava Agama Sruti and which don't?

Tags: vaishnavism, agamas, sruti

Do any Vaishnava sects consider Vaishnava agamas as "Sruti" by their own internal sectarian definition of "Sruti"?

Comment: Are you just looking for what Vaishnava sects accept the scriptural authority of Agamas, or are you specifically interested in the Shruti vs. Smriti issue?

Comment: By the way, for more information on the Pancharatra Agamas, which are the Agamas followed by most mainstream Vaishnavas, see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6896/36 Also, you may be interested in the Agama Pramanya, a work by Ramanujacharya's guru's guru Yamunacharya which defends the scriptural authority of Pancharatra Agama: https://archive.org/download/pancaratra-agamas/Agama%20Pramanyam%20%5BSkt-Eng%5D.pdf

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yes, I have read many of your questions and answers, they are very informative but I am specifically interested in Shruti vs Smriti issue in Vaishnava sampradAyas. I know Vaishnavas accept spiritual authority of Vaishnava Agama. I am curious to know if they consider them Sruti like Vedas. May be I will edit my question so that people who only know about one or two vaishnava sects can answer.