# What is the location of Vishnu's sacred place of Mallakupa?

Tags: vishnu, temple, shaivism, agamas

As I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6896/36), the Pancharatra Agamas are the foundational texts of Vaishnavism. Similarly, the foundational texts of Shaivism are known as the Shaiva Agamas, aka the Shaiva Tantras.  One of the oldest Shaiva Agamas is the Nishvasatattva Samhita, which is only preserved in a single manuscript from Nepal.

In any case, in [this excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wK7CJ.jpg) from the Nishvasatattva Samhita, various sacred places of Vishnu are described:

> Hari always resides in Shalagrama, Mallakupa, Saukarava, in Sannidhana, Mathura, as well as Shvetadvipa; having seen Vishnu ... one will be freed from all sins; people deceased in these places will go to that highest abode (paramam padam) of Vishnu.

Now most of these places are recognizable; Shalagrama is where the Muktinath Vishnu temple is located, Saukarava is where the Soron Varaha temple is located, Mathura is the birthplace of Krishna, and Shwetadvipa is the abode of Vishnu's Vyuha Vasudeva form, who lies down on the serpent Adiseshan.  But my question is, what is this Mallakupa place which is sacred to Vishnu?

The translator just says this:

> As far as we can see, this place sacred to Vishnu is attested only in our text and in the Shivadharmasangraha.

But does anyone know the location of this place?