# Is Vishnu a Vedic deity ? Are there any mantras attributed to him?

Tags: vishnu, vedas, samhita

Is there any mantra attributed to Vishnu in the Veda (moola samhita). Not mention of word "Vishnu" but is he a "devata" for any specific mantra for example "brahmanaspati" devata for "gana nan tva ganapati..."

Comment: Are you serious?! He is the main deity mentioned in vedas alongside Indra, Vayu, Agni, Soma, Ashwins and Rudras. He is author as well as devta for many mantras

Comment: @Yogi what mean by author ?

Comment: Sorry proper word is Rishi, he is Rishi and worshipped deity(as purusha) for Purusha suktam in narayana avatara.

Comment: @Yogi my question is not pertaining to puranas

Comment: How is Purusha suktam related to puranas.???

Comment: @Yogi I am specifically asking mantras to whom Vishnu is the devata.. if anyone knows answers with reference then its welcome

Comment: @RakeshJoshi btw, do you think Vedic Vishnu different from Puranic Vishnu like Vedic Rudra and Shiva?

Comment: @TheDestroyer I think it could be .. but there could be similarities also...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you can see in the Rig Veda Anukramani given in my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2430/36), Vishnu is the Devata of several hymns of the Rig Veda:

- [Book 1 Hymn 22](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01022.htm) Verses 16-21
- [Book 1 Hymn 154](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01154.htm)
- [Book 1 Hymn 155](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01155.htm)
- [Book 1 Hymn 156](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01156.htm)
- [Book 7 Hymn 99](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv07099.htm)
- [Book 7 Hymn 100](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv07100.htm)

Also, there are several hymns of the Rig Veda where the Rishis is either Vishnu  or one of his incarnations:

- [Book 10 Hymn 90](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10090.htm) was heard by Vishnu's incarnation sage Narayana.
- [Book 10 Hymn 110](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10110.htm) was heard by Vishnu's incarnation Parashurama
- [Book 10 Hymn 134](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10134.htm) was heard by Vishnu's incarnation Mandhata
- [Book 10 Hymn 148](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10148.htm) was heard by Vishnu's incarnation Prithu
- [Book 10 Hymn 184](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10184.htm) was heard by Vishnu himself

By the way, while the Devata may very from one hymn to another, all the hymns of the Vedas ultimately praise Vishnu.  As Krishna says in the Bhagavad Gita, " Those who are devotees of other gods and who worship them with faith actually worship only Me."

Comment: Thank you. Vishnu in the vedas is generally referred as son of Aditi and one among the 12 adityas (sun gods).

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Yes, because Vishnu's incarnation Vamana is the youngest son of Kashyapa and Aditi.  See my answer here for more details: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6896/36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I think incarnation concept is more of a puranic. does vedas favor incarnations ? I am not sure about it though.

Comment: **By the way, while the Devata may very from one hymn to another, all the hymns of the Vedas ultimately praise Vishnu.** Is that a new theory that u are currently developing? :D..And all worship ultimately reach the Brahman not necessarily any particular deity like Krishna..

Comment: @Rickross , no it's not new theory.. Krishna says that in Bhagavad Gita chap 9.23, that's why it is applicable to vedic hyms. Vyasa also says "vedashAstrAtparaM nAsti na daivaM keshavAtparam"... and you might have heard of shloka "sarva deva namaskaram keshavam pratigachati'. Keshava/Krishna is the Paramatma/Brahmam

Comment: @ram Krishna mite  be Brahman for u but not for me or others. And BG is not the only Gita.There r several others, with author being the same Vyasa. For Shaivites Shiva is Brahman. And Lalita Devi created Krishna and other avatars of Vishnu for her finger nails. Then for devotees of Sri Lalita how can any other deities (like Krishna etc) be Brahman? And mentioning Gita in a Q related to Veda Samhitas is perfectly redundant.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Yes, Vamana incarnation is mentioned in Rigveda http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01022.htm check 18th Richa...

Comment: @YDS do veda say that vamana and vishnu are same ? Does it have the word avatara?