# What scriptures describe the phenomenon of Fire Eclipses?

Tags: agamas, tantra, shaktism, eclipse

Just like Vaishnavas follow Pancharatra Agamas and Shaivites follow Shaiva Agamas, Shakta follow Shakta Agamas, aka Shakta Tantras. (I discuss an exception that proves the rule [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17749/36).) One such Shakta Agama is the Matrikabheda Tantra.  In [this excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8J8Gl.jpg) from the Matrikabheda Tantra, Shiva tells Parvati about different kinds of eclipses:

> Oh, listen to me! The eclipse is a very good occasion. It is of three kinds, relating to the Sun, Moon, or fire respectively. On the forehead of Sakti (Durga) fire exists, in her left eyes glows the Moon and in her right eye the Sunshine. These three types of eclipses originate differently at the time of union of Siva with Parvati.  When the left eye of Parvati is kissed by Siva, the lunar eclipse occurs. At the time of kissing of right eye the solar eclipse takes place and **at the time of his kissing the fore-head the fire­ eclipse is generated. But as the fire is the hidden energy of Siva hence fire eclipse can not be seen outwardly.**  Rahu, Siva and Sakti are considered to be three qualities. The union of Siva and Sakti causes eclipse. The time when Siva and Sakti unite is thought to be an auspicious hour pervaded with divinity or bliss.

Now solar eclipses and lunar eclipses are well-known astronomical phenomena. But my question is, what scriptures describe fire eclipses?

Also, the passage says that fire eclipses are not visible, but is it possible to calculate when they occur?  After all, Rahu, Ketu, and the other [Upagrahas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upagraha) or shadow planets are not visible, yet their location can still be calculated mathematically.  So is it similarly possible to mathematically calculate the location of the fire which is said to be "the hidden energy of Siva"?

Comment: Since they are not seen outwardly seen its unlikely that some scriptures will talk about them or discuss them in details. Probably Matrika Bheda Tantram is the only one to talk about such eclipses

Comment: @Rickross Well, if the Matrika Bheda Tantra talks about them, others may talk about them as well.  The Upagrahas are not seen outwardly, but they're still discussed.

Comment: Why does Shiva tell Parvati about Shiva and Parvati?

Comment: @Surya That is standard fare for Shaiva and Shakta Agamas.  A lot of them involve either Shiva telling Shakti about Shiva and Shakti, or Shakti telling Shiva about Shiva and Shakti.  Some Agamas actually comment on that trope, like Shakti will say "I know that you already know the answers to your questions, but you're just asking me so that our dialogue will benefit others."

Comment: Wow this is something new regarding the cause of eclipses!