# Which Vedic verses declare Lord Brahma as supreme?

Tags: vedas, worship, brahma, vedic-gods

Lord Brahmaa is a very important figure in Vedic tradition. He is referred to as PrajApatI and hiranyagarbha in the Vedas. As per Puranic tradition he is the part of trimurti's or trinity.

However, in the present era Lord Brahmaa and his worship has been sidelined. Only the two other gods of the trinity are given more importance.

There are puranic stories about brahma being cursed and hence his worship is forbidden in the present era.

Like the other Vedic gods (Indra, Varuna, Mitra, Soma etc.) his worship is also sidelined due to some reason or another.

**I want to know which verses or hymns of the Vedas declare Lord Brahma as supreme or highest?**

**When we can venerate Lord Brahma in the Vedic rituals then why not in general regular worship?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I want to know which verses or hymns of the Vedas declare Lord Brahma as supreme or highest?**

**Yajurveda Shatapatha Brahmana 6.1.3.1** declares Lord Brahma as Supreme. This is already discussed in [How were the Trimurthi born?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/237/how-were-the-trimurthi-born)

You have answered this in your question itself. Lord Brahma is a very important figure in Vedic tradition. He is referred to as PrajApatI and Hiranyagarbha in the Vedas. This is also discussed [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20894/are-the-vedic-gods-prajapati-and-brahma-the-same).

Also, if Lord Brahma is Prajapati then there are many verses or hymns dedicated to Prajapati and considered him as supreme as [Indra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22400/is-indra-the-chief-god-of-the-vedas), [Agni](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22574/do-any-verses-in-the-vedas-declare-agni-to-be-supreme), [Surya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11416/why-is-lord-surya-also-called-suryanarayana) (or [Sun](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21307/which-scriptures-or-vedic-hymns-declare-the-sun-as-the-supreme-god-brahman)) and [Vishnu](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19872/do-any-vedic-verses-depict-lord-vishnu-to-be-supreme).

**When we can venerate Lord Brahma in the Vedic rituals then why not in general regular worship?**

Due to two curses. However neither the below mentioned curses makes Lord Brahma inferior to other two Gods in Trinity. He still remains the God of Creation and has the equal importance as other two Gods in Trinity.

Only his worship is not popular or limited. [Are there any eulogies and prayers to Brahma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22596/are-there-any-eulogies-and-prayers-to-brahma)
**There is a temple of Lord Bhrahma in Pushkar, Rajasthan**, I have visited this temple.

I. Lord Shiva cursed Lord Brahma

As per [Shiva Purana](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/shiva_purana/greatness_of_shivalinga_pillar_of_fire_omkar.php)

> "You spoke untruth with a desire to become worshippable. It is my curse that, you will not be worshipped by anybody. You will posses only four heads."

**Note:** People only talk about curse, they should remember that in Shiva Purana, along with curse, Lord Shiva gave Brahma

> **a boon of being the presiding deity of all the yagya**.

So in yagya, directly on indirectly Lord Brahma is worshiped.

II. Sage Bhrigu cursed Lord Brahma

As per [Padma Purana](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/padma_purana/lord_vishnu_the_almighty_god.html)

> Sage Bhrigu became furious and cursed Lord Brahma--"Being intoxicated by your Rajoguna, you have shown disrespect to me. From today onwards people will not worship you."