# Are there any eulogies and prayers to Brahma?

Tags: scripture, brahma, prayer, hymn

Brahma is doubtlessly a most important God in Hinduism.

He is the Creator of the Universe in the Trinity of Shiva Vishnu Brahma.

Just because Shiva banished Brahma's worship, and it is said that Brahma is transient, so any person starts insulting Brahmaa.

We forget that Brahma is LokaPitaamaha and JagatSrashtaa. He is one of trinities and even if he is transient or not worshipped, he is to be respected.

Anyways, the question is there might be some Prayers to Brahma or at least praises to Lord Brahma.

Kindly give the praises to Lord Brahma The Supreme Creator of Universe.

Comment: But you are also doing the same what people do by supporting such views. If you really want to know actual fact than just refer vedic position of brahma or prajApati or hirangagarbha. It is not good to ignore vedic worship on puranic grounds. Lord brahma as equal to narayana and rudra.

Comment: Since Brahma created himself, he is called Svayambhu, born (bhu) by himself (svayam). People only talk aboout curse why they don't remeber that in Shiva Purana, along with curse, Lord Shiva gave Brahma a boon of being the presiding deity of all the yagya ( http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/shiva_purana/greatness_of_shivalinga_pillar_of_fire_omkar.php ).

Comment: As Lord Brahma was first Prajapati, eulogies and prayers to Prajapati Brahma can be found in Rigveda...

Comment: Your question is partially related with https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19893/which-vedic-verses-declare-lord-brahma-as-supreme/22601#22601

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19893/7853

Comment: There is a temple of Lord Bhrahma in Pushkar, Rajasthan, I have visited this temple.

Comment: Are you the same Anurag Singh?

Comment: @Parikshitha yes I am that Anurag.

Comment: @Parikshitha yes agnostic. In fact, I am kind of on verge of atheism.

Comment: Is any scripture describes about the dhyan shloka of Brahma by which we can know about his body complexion & physical look? @KeshavSrinivasan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Brahma Too is prayed by Rishis and Munis.

In **Shiva Puraana, Vaayaveeya Sanhita, PoorvaBhaaga, Chapter 2** -

> तं दृष्ट्वा मुनयः सर्वे प्रसन्नवदनेक्षणाः ।
>   शिरस्यञ्जलिमाधाय तुष्टुवुः सुरपुङ्गवम् ॥ १७ ॥
>
> **Seeing Brahmaa all the Munis with extremely delighted face and eyes, touched their folded hands to their heads and venerated the Best of Devas thus-**
>
> **मुनय ऊचुः I
>
>   नमस्त्रिमूर्तये तुभ्यं सर्गस्थित्यन्तहेतवे ।
>
>   पुरुषाय पुराणाय ब्रह्मणे परमात्मने ॥ १८ ॥
>
>   नमः प्रधानदेहाय प्रधानक्षोभकारिणे ।
>
>   त्रयोविंशतिभेदेन विकृतायाविकारिणे ॥ १९  ॥
>
>   नमो ब्रह्माण्डदेहाय ब्रह्माण्डोदरवर्तिने ।
>
>   तत्र संसिद्धकार्याय संसिद्धकरणाय च ॥ २० ॥
>
>   नमोऽस्तु सर्वलोकाय सर्वलोकविधायिने ।
>
>   सर्वात्मदेहसंयोगवियोगविधिहेतवे ॥ २१ ॥
>
>   त्वयैव निखिलं सृष्टं संहृतं पालितं जगत् ।
>
>   तथापि मायया नाथ न विद्मस्त्वां पितामह ॥ २२ ॥**
>
> **The Munis said -**
>   **Obeisances to Thee O Brahma! Thou art the Trimurti and Thou performest Creation, Preservation and Dissolution.**
>
> **Thou art the Ancient Purusha, obeisances to Thee who art the Supreme Soul.**
>
> **Thou assumest the Supreme Body, and Thou agitatest the Pradhaana Tattva and Thou transformest into the twenty three Tattvas, but again Thou art free from their influence.**
>
> **Obeisances to Thee who hast the whole Universe as His body, and Thou art established within the Universe. Thou accomplishedst Thy task and Thou bestowest accomplishment in tasks.**
>
> **Thou art the Whole Existence and Thou createst the Whole Existence.**
>
> **Thou art the one who ordaineth the entering and leaving of Atmaa in a body.**
>
> **O Brahmaa! It is only Thou by whom this whole existence is created, sustained and destroyed,**
>
> **Even then, by Thy Maayaa O Lord! we do not know Thee O Grandsire!**