# What is meant by Lord Vishnu as protector?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, dharma, symbolism

I would like a more detailed meaning of this. Whom does he protect? From what does he protect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How has Lord Vishnu's understanding developed and what was his role initially?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6870/how-has-lord-vishnus-understanding-developed-and-what-was-his-role-initially)

Answer (score 2):

> Whom does he protect?

He protects all living entities.

> From what does he protect?

From adharma and from those who are followers of adharma.

In this shloka of Bhagavad Gita Lord Krishna explained his role of protector to Arjuna by telling him that whenever needed he comes to protect ...

> यदा यदा हि धर्मस्य ग्लानिर्भवति भारत ।
>   अभ्युत्थानमधर्मस्य तदात्मानं सृजाम्यहम्‌॥४-७॥

भावार्थ :  हे भारत! जब-जब धर्म की हानि और अधर्म की वृद्धि होती है, तब-तब ही मैं अपने रूप को रचता हूँ अर्थात साकार रूप से लोगों के सम्मुख प्रकट होता हूँ॥

Meaning : Whenever and wherever there is a decline in religious practice, O descendant of Bharata, and a predominant rise of irreligion—at that time I descend Myself.

> परित्राणाय साधूनां विनाशाय च दुष्कृताम् । 
>   धर्मसंस्थापनार्थाय सम्भवामि युगे युगे ॥४-८॥

भावार्थ :  साधु पुरुषों का उद्धार करने के लिए, पाप कर्म करने वालों का विनाश करने के लिए और धर्म की अच्छी तरह से स्थापना करने के लिए मैं युग-युग में प्रकट हुआ करता हूँ॥

Meaning : In order to deliver the pious and to annihilate the miscreants, as well as to reestablish the principles of religion, I advent Myself millennium after millennium.