# Is it possible to live like in Krita Yuga [Satya Yuga] for an individual, despite being in Kali Yuga?

Tags: karma, yoga, yuga, sadhana, samadhi

Being inspired by this very extensive answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9205/22667
to a question about Yugas,
I would like to know if, applying all the human efforts and energies to sadhana and following the duties or renouncing to the fruits of our actions, as adviced in Bhagavad Geeta [Niskara Karma, renunciation of actions or Karma Yoga that is renunciation of fruits from the performed actions] one person can build a own inner peace of mind, which allow the practicioner of yoga to feel like in Satya Yuga, while living in Kali Yuga.

---

When you quote a Shastra, do provide

• Evaluable link [e.g. BORI, Sanskrit Documents]

• IAST (romanized) transliteration

• Verbatim translations from Sanskrit to English [see greenmes.org to know what I mean]

Thank you
Sanātanī.

I wish to add that Yog as experience is also evaluable as an answer, for me in this case.

---

Editing for Stack Exchange requirements:

Some Smrtris passages, Mahabharata and Hindu daily life experiences of people are My pre-requisites. I am ok with the answers streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may already know, in Hinduism Dharma is represented as a Bull having four feet. In Krita Yuga, the Bull has its four legs intact. So, Dharma is fully functional in that age. In Treta the Bull has 3 legs, in Dwapara 2 and finally in Kali Yuga the Dharma-Bull is standing on just one leg. In other words the Bull barely can stand and Dharma falls apart in Kali Yuga.

From Manu Smriti:

> 1.81. In the Krita age Dharma is four-footed and entire, and (so is) Truth; nor does any gain accrue to men by unrighteousness.
>
> 1.82. In the other (three ages), by reason of (unjust) gains (agama), Dharma is deprived successively of one foot, and through (the
> prevalence of) theft, falsehood, and fraud the merit (gained by men)
> is diminished by one fourth (in each)

Now, since this very nature of the fact, that 3 out of the 4 pillars of Dharma are non-fuctional in Kali Yuga, can't be changed by anybody among us shows no matter how much we try we can't follow a Satya Yuga lifestyle in the Kali Yuga. Because the nature of the Yuga itself is such that it does not have all the pillars of Dharma intact in it.

So, it is neither possible nor desired according to me. Because Yuga Dharma has to prevail.

Comment: thank you. So in which way can we satisfy pre-requisites to follow the Righteousness of the Purushartas? In which way the yoga will be good?

Comment: In order to satisfy the Dharma part of the Purusharthas we simply have to follow Yuga Dharma. In Kali Yuga only Truth (one of the 4 limbs of the Bull) is intact. So, we have to be truthful. If we sacrifice Truth also then the Bull is devoid of all the 4 legs. Anyway, according scriptures Kali Yuga Dharma is charity (dana) and nama japa (chanting holy names) @hindustudent

Comment: that is why in my sadhana I felt , "heard" Shiva telling me "nirvikalpa ko atheindrya gyaan" and hence never to tell lies in association to a more fast and precise travel to Moksha ? Dana is important also yes! Please send me all the Gyaan that You have! adunaton88 [at] protonmail [dot] com. Mail whatever You have. Thank you

Comment: I have noted down your email. I am not that knowledgeable though. Like you I'm also looking for more and true knowledge.@hindustudent

Comment: mere drhrd iccha shakti look for help, give help if i am eligible to do such. share, know and mitraon. Ji you can contact me for anything. @Rickross

Comment: Sure I am keeping that in mind :) @hindustudent

Comment: can you get my poor Hindi? @Rickross

Comment: Yes more or less although my mother tongue isn't Hindi it's Bengali. @hindustudent

Comment: Oh i love it!!!!! Jay Maa Dhoomavati!!! I must go to Assam and Bengala. Jay Maa Lalita Devi, Jay Maa Katyayani Rickross, tumaro priye :D Bengali is so similar to Sanskrit! @Rickross

Comment: Haha .. yes you are right .. it's quite similar.@hindustudent

Comment: you can teach me Bengali, through wich I will improve my Sanskrit ;) please Ji. Talk to me in your mesmerizing beautiful language I feel the shadows and lights of Maa Kali inside it. @Rickross

Answer (score 1):

That the Yugas are primarily dependent on the character and outlook of an individual is made clear in Vedic texts such as Aitareya Brahmana. As society and the nation is made up of individuals, the whole society and nation will move into Krita Yuga or Kali Yuga depending on whether individuals are themselves in the mentality of Krita Yuga or Kali Yuga.

The Aitareya Brahmana has a beautiful way of expressing what the Yugas really mean. This is a very famous section in the story of Harishcandra.

Aitareya Brahmana 33.3.3:

> कलिः शयानो भवति संजिहानस्तु द्वापरः ।
> उत्तिष्ठंस्त्रेता भवति कृतं संपद्यते चरंश्चरैवेति ॥
> Kali is when one sleeps, Dvapara is when he wakes up, Treta is when he stands up, and Krta is when he walks. Hence always walk (i.e. be dynamic).

> चरन् वै मधु विन्दति चरन् स्वादुमुदुम्बरम् ।
> सूर्यस्य पश्य श्रेमाणं यो न तन्द्रयते चरंश्चरैवेति ॥
> Only by walking does one find honey, only by walking does one find sweet fruits. Look at the excellence of the Sun, who is always walking and never gets lazy or fatigued. Hence always walk (i.e. be dynamic).

So you see, Kaliyuga is really the state of ignorance and laziness, whereas Satya (or Krta) Yuga is really the state of knowledge and dynamism.

These verses are full of deep and meaningful symbolisms. 'Honey' and 'sweet fruits' can stand for either good results in this world or the highest spiritual achievement.

This is the true wise meaning of Yugas.

Answer (score 0):

One should remember that the position of all in this age of Kali is :-
  ..

prāyeṇālpāyuṣaḥ sabhya
kalāv asmin yuge janāḥ
mandāḥ sumanda-matayo
manda-bhāgyā hy upadrutāḥ

" O learned one, in this iron age of Kali men have but short lives. They are quarrelsome, lazy, misguided, unlucky and, above all, always disturbed. "

From ,  ,  ,  ,

अनुग्रहो मे सुमहांस्तृप्तिश्च तव दर्शनात् ⁠।
एकं तु कृतमिच्छामि त्वयाद्य प्रियमात्मनः ⁠।⁠।⁠ ३ ⁠।⁠।

Bhimasena Said to Hanuman
" You have been very kind to me. Your Presence has given me great pleasure. Now I want to fulfill  one more auspicious desire by you again. "

यत् ते तदाऽऽसीत् प्लवतः सागरं मकरालयम् ⁠।
रूपमप्रतिमं वीर तदिच्छामि निरीक्षितुम् ⁠।⁠।⁠ ४ ⁠।⁠।
एवं तुष्टो भविष्यामि श्रद्धास्यामि च ते वचः ⁠।
एवमुक्तः स तेजस्वी प्रहस्य हरिरब्रवीत् ⁠।⁠।⁠ ५ ⁠।⁠।

" O Great Warrior  I am having a great desire to see the unique gigantic form you took while crossing the sea of ​​Makralaya(when Sri Hanuman crossed 100 yojanas to Lanka). I will be satisfied to see that divine form of yours, you will be revered. When Bhimsen said this, Hanumanji laughed and said- "

न तच्छक्यं त्वया द्रष्टुं रूपं नान्येन केनचित् ⁠।
कालावस्था तदा ह्यन्या वर्तते सा न साम्प्रतम् ⁠।⁠।⁠ ६ ⁠।⁠।

" Brother! You cannot see that form, no other human being can see it. At that time the stage was different, now it is no more. "

अन्यः कृतयुगे कालस्त्रेतायां द्वापरे परः ⁠।
अयं प्रध्वंसनः कालो नाद्य तद् रूपमस्ति मे ⁠।⁠।⁠ ७ ⁠।⁠।
भूमिर्नद्यो नगाः शैलाः सिद्धा देवा महर्षयः ⁠।
कालं समनुवर्तन्ते यथा भावा युगे युगे ⁠।⁠।⁠ ८ ⁠।⁠।
बलवर्ष्मप्रभावा हि प्रहीयन्त्युद्भवन्ति च ⁠।
तदलं बत तद् रूपं द्रष्टुं कुरुकुलोद्वह ⁠।
युगं समनुवर्तामि कालो हि दुरतिक्रमः ⁠।⁠।⁠ ९ ⁠।⁠।

"  ❜          .        .       . , , , , ,    -        .    ,       ,      .  .       .       ;          . "

But then again since Hanuman being a Pure Devotee of Lord Ram, he did show his gigantic  form transcending the strictures of time(kala, yuga)

भीमसेन उवाच
पूर्वरूपमदृष्ट्वा ते न यास्यामि कथंचन ⁠।
यदि तेऽहमनुग्राह्यो दर्शयात्मानमात्मना ⁠।⁠।⁠ १ ⁠।⁠।

Bhimasena Said
" O most merciful  I will not go any way without seeing that divine gaigantic form of yours. Kindly favour me , and  reveal yourself to me. "

वैशम्पायन उवाच
एवमुक्तस्तु भीमेन स्मितं कृत्वा प्लवंगमः ⁠।
तद् रूपं दर्शयामास यद् वै सागरलङ्घने ⁠।⁠।⁠ २ ⁠।⁠।

Vaishampayana said
" When Bhimsen said so , Hanuman smiled and showed him his form, which he had taken up at the time of crossing the sea to Lanka "

.
भ्रातुः प्रियमभीप्सन् वै चकार सुमहद् वपुः ⁠।
देहस्तस्य ततोऽतीव वर्धत्यायामविस्तरैः ⁠।⁠।⁠ ३ ⁠।⁠।
सद्रुमं कदलीषण्डं छादयन्नमितद्युतिः ⁠।
गिरेश्चोच्छ्रयमाक्रम्य तस्थौ तत्र च वानरः ⁠।⁠।⁠ ४ ⁠।⁠।
उन्होंने अपने भाईका प्रिय करनेकी इच्छासे अत्यन्त

" Hanuman took up his huge gaigantic form with a desire to please his brother. His body became very large in length, breadth and height. They stood there, covering the height of the Gandhamadan mountain, covering the entire Kadalivan, including the immense stunning monkey trees. "

Comment: please can u provide more IAST and verbatim translation? Thank you @Krsna Dasa

Comment: Why? @Krsna Dasa? It lacks of IAST but is your point of view from scriptures.

Comment: prāyeṇa---almost always; alpa---meager; āyuṣaḥ---duration of life; sabhya---member of a learned society; kalau---in this age of Kali (quarrel); asmin---herein; yuge---age; janāḥ---the public; mandāḥ---lazy; sumanda-matayaḥ---misguided; manda-bhāgyāḥ---unlucky; hi---and above all; upadrutāḥ---disturbed. It is right @Krsna Dasa what Srimad Bhagavatam states. At least you provided sources. You say "can't". Ok. This is your point of view.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question whether it can be followed is yes.
But it is not recommended by the yuga dharma. The yuga dharma is designed in such a way that it is possible for the people living during those yugas to follow it and get the appropriate fruit and moksha.

Similarly in Kali Yuga it's not possible for any ordinary man to practice yuga dharmas of other yugas. Kali Yuga recommends chanting holy name of the lord because in Kali Yuga people are overcome by heavy material desires and effect of Maya and Kali reduces the ability of humans to understand dharma. Chanting holy name of the lord easily helps us lift ourselves to a higer level according to the Yuga dharma.

Comment: Om Namah Shivaya, Shivaya Namaha 

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps these passages from the Srimad Bhagavatam may be relevant to your question?

[Srimad Bhagavatam 12:3](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/12/3/)

**SB 12.3.18**

> श्रीशुक उवाच
> कृते प्रवर्तते धर्मश्चतुष्पात्तज्जनैर्धृत: ।
> सत्यं दया तपो दानमिति पादा विभोर्नृप ॥ १८ ॥
>
> śrī-śuka uvāca
> kṛte pravartate dharmaś
> catuṣ-pāt taj-janair dhṛtaḥ
> satyaṁ dayā tapo dānam
> iti pādā vibhor nṛpa
>
> Śukadeva Gosvāmī said: My dear King, in the beginning, during Satya-yuga, the age of truth, religion is
> present with all four of its legs intact and is
> carefully maintained by the people of that age. These
> four legs of powerful religion are truthfulness, mercy,
> austerity and charity.

**SB 12.3.19**

> सन्तुष्टा: करुणा मैत्रा: शान्ता दान्तास्तितिक्षव: ।
> आत्मारामा: समद‍ृश: प्रायश: श्रमणा जना: ॥ १९ ॥
>
> santuṣṭāḥ karuṇā maitrāḥ
> śāntā dāntās titikṣavaḥ
> ātmārāmāḥ sama-dṛśaḥ
> prāyaśaḥ śramaṇā janāḥ
>
> The people of Satya-yuga are for the most part self-satisfied, merciful, friendly to all, peaceful, sober
> and tolerant. They take their pleasure from within, see
> all things equally and always endeavor diligently for
> spiritual perfection.

**SB 12.3.27**

> प्रभवन्ति यदा सत्त्वे मनोबुद्धीन्द्रियाणि च ।
> तदा कृतयुगं विद्याज्ज्ञाने तपसि यद् रुचि: ॥ २७ ॥
>
> prabhavanti yadā sattve
> mano-buddhīndriyāṇi ca
> tadā kṛta-yugaṁ vidyāj
> jñāne tapasi yad ruciḥ
>
> **When the mind, intelligence and senses are solidly
> fixed in the mode of goodness, that time should be
> understood as Satya-yuga, the age of truth.** People
> then take pleasure in knowledge and austerity.
>
> Purport:
>
> The word kṛta means “performed” or “executed.” Thus in
> the age of truth all religious duties are duly
> performed, and people take great pleasure in spiritual
> knowledge and austerity. **Even in the Kali-yuga, those
> who are situated in the mode of goodness take pleasure
> in the cultivation of spiritual knowledge and the
> regulated performance of austerity.** This sublime
> state of existence is possible for one who has conquered sex desire.

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

While the word 'krita' is often translated as 'completed', it more properly means: self-accomplished, self-completed, self-realized, self-achieved, done by self, etc. So, by definition, the answer is automatically no, at least, for the majority of people - there will naturally always be individuals who are more skillful or extraordinary than the average person in their time.

The krita-yuga represents a time where every person can achieve the desires of their heart with ease - they are healthier and smarter, lost ancient knowledge is regained, resources are more abundant, etc. Such is also what makes it satya-yuga, the yuga of truth, because there is no need or burden for people to lie or be dishonest with one another. A time when everyone is healthy, beautiful, smart, long-lived, and resources are plentiful.

The decline overtime can be attributed to many things, and we really don't have to look very far to see this: 10,000+ years ago the Middle East was a forested grassland, rather than a desert, but growth of population and excessive farming lead to depletion of soil and general resources, which then lead to conflict, struggle, etc. Inevitably greedy rulers began to suppress powerful knowledge, which then leads to a further decline and weakening of the population at large.

A curious fact is that the [Sumerian King list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumerian_King_List) reports that, prior to the flood, they had individual Kings whom ruled for 20,000-40,000 years at a time. Inevitably, such long lifespans would also contribute to the self-realization capacity that people had during that time period. Notably the King list shows that the lifespans dropped down to 1000 years immediately after the flood.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/42619/do-brahma-vishnu-and-shiva-represent-cosmic-energy-cosmic-space-and-cosmic-tim/43875#comment136415_43875