# How has Devī Lakshmī 's understanding developed, starting from the Vedic literature up until the recent times?

Tags: vedas, vishnu, puranas, history, lakshmi

Similar to [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6870/how-has-lord-vishnus-understanding-developed-and-what-was-his-role-initially), which **tries to discuss** about the trajectory of Lord *Vishnu's* theological development and understanding, from the *Vedic* period to the *Paurāṇika* period.
I'd like to get an understanding of *Devī Lakshmī* vis-a-vis her eternal consort, Lord *Vishnu*, starting from the *Vedic* Literature period to the *Paurāṇika* period and to the current times.

How much, has she been correlated or been mentioned (either explicitly or implicitly) to be Lord *Vishnu's* consort in the Vedic literature?

What spheres did *Devī Lakshmī* initially preside over in the *Vedic* Literature and which spheres, possibly belonging to some non-Vedic deities, were further added to her domain, thus, turning her into an over-arching Mother Goddess in the *purāṇas* ?

Comment: Well you have the Rigveda mentioning Lakshmi as Vishnu’s consort and bestower of wealth.