# As per Shiva Purana what are the 28 avatars of Shiva as said to Brahma?

Tags: shiva, avatars, shiva-purana

As per Shiva Purana which 28 avatars of Shiva did he tell to Brahma? Also Shiva said the names of Sage Vyasa of each Mahayuga. What are those?

Comment: What do you mean by 27 Kalpa? Do you mean 27th Kalpa? [These two Chapters](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/10689/12959/3/Chapter1_1070-1148p.pdf) of Shiva Puranas explain different avatars of Shiva in each Mahayuga in this Vaivasra Manvantara of Sweta Varaha Kalpa. For different Vyass in each Mahayuga, see [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9386/3500).

Comment: No one by one kalpa happens and in every kalpa shiva's avatars will incranate. That description is given in shiv purana. But I forgot.

Comment: Those chapters describe various Yogavatars of Shiva who specially incarnated to teach Yoga techniques to people of Kali Yuga in every Mahayuga. It looks like you mistook Mahayuga for Kalpa. Read the chapter of Shiva Purana i linked in my 1st comment.

Comment: ved vyasa names i see but shiva avatars?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chapter [4](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/siva-mahapurana/vol-ii/chapter-83/topic-1) and [5](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/siva-mahapurana/vol-ii/chapter-84/topic-1) of Satarudrasamhita of Shiva Purana describes the 28 Avatars of Shiva. Shiva takes these avatars at end of every Dvapara Yuga with  Vyasa to teach Yoga techniques for people of Kali Yuga. He will have 4 disciples in each Yuga and these disciples teach the people of Kali Yuga and help them in liberation. These are the names of Avatars of Shiva in chronological order in this Vaivastara Manvnatara of Svetavaraha Kalpa.

> 1. Sveta muni
> 2. Sutaara
> 3. Damana
> 4. Suhotra
> 5. Kanka
> 6. Lokaaksi
> 7. Jaigeesaavya
> 8. Dashivaahana
> 9. Rsabha (well known Avatar of Shiva)
> 10. Brgu
> 11. Kaali
> 12. Puru
> 13. Bali
> 14. Gautama
> 15. Vedavarsin
> 16. Gokarna
> 17. Grhasvami
> 18. Sikhandi
> 19. Jaatimali
> 20. Attahas
> 21. Daaruka
> 22. Laanguli Bheema
> 23. Sveta
> 24. Sooli
> 25. Dandi
> 26. Sahinsu
> 27. Somasarma
> 28. Yogatma and becomes popular by name Lakuli.
>
> Lakuli is identified as [Lakulish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakulish) who revived
> Pasupata Sect.

For different Vyasas, see [this answer.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9386/3500)

**Note**: Shiva Purana doesn't contain some names. So, those names are taken from [Kurma Purana](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/10689/21487/7/Part1_Chapter5_293-336p.pdf) (Pg No- 333)

Comment: Is it rishabha?

Comment: @SreeCharan Rshba is sage while Sharabha is bird. You can read story of Rshba from Satarudra Samhita of Shiva Purana.