# What is the name of the person who reconciled a line from Rudram to dakshinamurthy and Adi Shankaracharya?

Tags: shiva, adi-shankaracharya

Consider the following lines from [Rudram](https://shaivam.org/scripture/English-Translation/1431/rudram-english-translation) and their translation

> Nama kapardhine cha vyupthakesaya cha
>
> Salutations to him who has a crown of hair and to him who has a shaved head

I heard that a person reconciled the above line as follows

**The Siva with crown of hair is Dakshinamurthy and with shaved head is Adi Shankaracharya**

What is the name of the person who gave the above statement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Abhinava Shankara](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15126/3500) in his commentary on Rudram says Vyuptakesha refers to Sri Adi Shankara Bhagavadpada. Sri Chandrashekarendra Saraswati Mahaswamigal says the same and quotes Abhinava Shankara's commentary as reference.

[This](https://www.kamakotimandali.com/advaita/shambhormurti.html) is what Sri Chandrasekharendra Saraswati Mahaswamigal says in one of the talks:

> In addition to being the several things of this world, there are also
>   the names of the form of parameshvara which we know. These are called
>   asAdharaNa nAmas. Usually, we understand sAdhAraNam as ordinary and
>   asAdharaNam as something special or rare. The fact is sAdhAraNam means
>   what is general and asAdhAraNam means what is specific. When
>   paramashiva is referred to as the several things of the world, such
>   reference will be in the plural form and the asAdhAraNa names which
>   are exclusive to paramashiva are mentioned in singular. While
>   mentioning names specific to shiva, it is said, bhava, rudra, sharva,
>   pashupati, nIlakaNTha, shitikaNTha; note that the names are all in
>   singular. After the name shitikaNTha, the two names kapardI and
>   vyuptakesha are mentioned with namaskAram immediately followed by
>   sahasrAkSha (one with countless eyes) and shatadhanvan (one with
>   countless weapons). Then the names girIsha and girisha are mentioned
>   which which are specific to shiva are also mentioned. Thus, due to the
>   occurrence in the midst of the several asAdhAraNa nAmas appropriate
>   only to parameshvara, the names kapardin and vyuptakesha are listed,
>   it means that these two are also specific to Him.
>
> What is meant by kapardin and vyuptakesha? Kapardin means the one who
>   is having jaTA. Vyuptakesha means the one who is having a shaven head.
>   In rudra, names given to Ishvara in succession are opposites in
>   quality. He is jyeShTha and he is kaniShTha. In the same manner, he is
>   the one with jaTA and the one with the shaven head. But there is
>   something special about kapardi. Kaparda means jaTA. But it does not
>   refer to the jaTA of everyone. Only the jaTA of parameshvara is called
>   kaparda. When mahAviShNu, brahmA, indra, and all the other devas are
>   wearing a kirITa on their heads, it is only shiva, the yogi, who is
>   with jaTA. Only parameshvara who wears the gangA, the moon, the snake,
>   the kapAla, the dhatUra flower etc. has been specifically given the
>   name kapardI. It is therefore a confirmation that this name refers
>   only to parameshvara.
>
> Therefore, the name vyuptakesha which comes immediately after kapardi
>   must also be specific to paramashiva. This name does not appear in
>   between the names such as the carpenters, potters, fishermen,
>   outcaste, thieves etc., but instead between those names which refer to
>   Him as the only one Ishvara who is the Lord of the world. These two
>   names are mentioned in singular referring to Ishvara only. We have
>   seen that kapardi is the asAdhAraNa nAma specific to him; therefore
>   the name vyuptakesha should also be such based on the pattern. This is
>   an important point we should make note of.
>
> Thus, the name vyuptakesha refers to the form of sannyAsin with shaved
>   head, which is specific to paramashiva. **There is no mUrti other than
>   our AchArya which can be shown as with a shaven head. Whether it is
>   dakShiNAmUrti, naTarAja or tripurAri, all these mUrtis are with jaTAs.
>   When it is so and the veda clearly refers to a particular mUrti of
>   paramashiva as vyuptakesha, it only refers to the shankara avatAra
>   which is to take place in the future. This is how abhinava shankara
>   who has commented on the rudram has explained this nAma**.
>
> Will it be enough if we say that when rudram specifically mentions a
>   person with shaven head as shiva svarUpi, it is specifically our
>   AchArya? It will be satisfying only if some other authority is also
>   shown. This is where we examine the purANas. It is the way of our
>   elders that the meaning of the veda should be understood only through
>   purANAs and itihAsas.