# Where can I find a reference to all the avatars of Mahadev?

Tags: shiva, avatars

I came to know from a friend that the lord Mahadev had 11 Maha-avatars like Piplad, Veer-bhadra, Grihpati etc,.

Can anyone help me out that from where can I get information about all of them?

Thanks.

Comment: no, not a duplicate as I asked about the Maha-Avtars.

refer the below link. Here, it mentions a small detail for the same. I wish to know in brief about them.

https://www.boldsky.com/yoga-spirituality/faith-mysticism/2014/nineteen-avatars-of-lord-shiva-038512.html

Comment: This may help also : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12337/as-per-shiva-purana-what-are-the-28-avatars-of-shiva-as-said-to-brahma/13561#13561